# Array merge failed

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

maybe it's simple as it look, but it driving me crazy.
Here's my array :

```
$result =
Array

 (
   [0] => Array
        (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 4
        [3] => 4
        [4] => 4
        [5] => 4
        [6] => 4
        [7] => 4
        [8] => 4
        [9] => 4
        [10] => 40
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 4
        [3] => 4
        [4] => 4
        [5] => 4
        [6] => 4
        [7] => 4
        [8] => 4
        [9] => 4
        [10] => 41
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 5
        [3] => 5
        [4] => 5
        [5] => 5
        [6] => 5
        [7] => 5
        [8] => 5
        [9] => 5
        [10] => 50
    )
```

)

this is what i want transformed into :

after array_merge:

```
  $result =
 Array
(
[0] => 4
[1] => 4
[2] => 4
[3] => 4
[4] => 4
[5] => 4
[6] => 4
[7] => 4
[8] => 4
[9] => 4
[10] => 40
[11] => 5
[12] => 4
[13] => 4
[14] => 4
[15] => 4
[16] => 4
[17] => 4
[18] => 4
[19] => 4
[20] => 4
[21] => 41
[22] => 5
[23] => 5
[24] => 5
[25] => 5
[26] => 5
[27] => 5
[28] => 5
[29] => 5
[30] => 5
[31] => 5
[32] => 50
)
```

this is the code :

```
    <?php 
        $result = array(); 
    ?>
    @foreach ($detail_ratings as $detail_rating)
    <?php $result[] = json_decode($detail_rating); ?>

    @endforeach
    <?php 
    $result = array_merge($result[0],$result[1],$result[2]);
     ?>
    {{print_r($result)}}
```

how do i make it automatically without manually using this code :

```
  $result = array_merge($result[0],$result[1],$result[2]);
```

this is what i already did :

```
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        $values[] =  array_merge($value,$result[$key]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
$result=array();
foreach($values as $value) {
    $result = array_merge($result,$value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help :-

```
 function nameit(array $arr)
    {
        $newarr = array();
        foreach($arr as $a => $b)
        {
            $newarr[] = $b;
        }
        return $newarr;
    }
```

Comment: where do i place it ? inside foreach?

Comment: You can call the funcion nameit($somearray) and it will return the array in the format you wanted, where $somearray is the array you want to transform.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$final_array = array_merge($array1,$array2);
```

Comment: but i need to automatically merge it